# How to continue playing when return to activity use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

In my application I am using `RecyclerView` to list and play songs from server. I use `RecyclerView` and `OnItemClickListener` in order to go to new activity and play song with extras from main activity, but `startActivity` in `RecyclerView` need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and when use them in `MediaPlayer` which does not work after come back to play activity. I mean, `onCreate` is called!.How to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? Please post some code and provide more details about what the problem is.

Comment: You should use `Service` to play songs

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` requirement could be because you're using the application context to start a new activity? don't do that (generally) if you have an activity context available

Comment: @adnbsr  please some sample for help . tnx

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer